# Is the radio attenuation of an obstructed 2.4GHz signal, dependent on its incident power?

Tags: propagator, radio, radio-frequency, attenuation

The following figure (taken from [CTS 115: Free Space Path Loss](https://www.cleartosend.net/cts-115-free-space-path-loss/)) describes generally how obstructions attenuate a 2.4GHz signal: [image: Free Space Path Loss Model]

I would like to ask, is this -3dB loss dependent on the power (or distance from the source) of the incident signal? If yes, how significantly?

I made the following figure to illustrate my question:

[image: Question Illustration]

So, would the OUT(coming) signals still be -3dB if this specific wall was either at 1m or 16m away from the source?

Answer (score 0):

There are two regimes for losses like this, often called “linear” and “non-linear”.

In the linear, low-power regime, losses (in dB) just add. There’s no power dependence to the loss, because the material is responding linearly: more incident power just generates more lost power proportionally.

But at *much* higher powers, the incident power can change material properties. (Think microwave oven power levels). Then the loss can either increase or decrease with power instead of staying the same.

Comment: It really depends what the material is that the signal is propagating through. A typical "wall" probably does need microwave oven power levels to go nonlinear, but we could design a material or a metamaterial to have nonlinear behavior at much lower power levels. (And we should be saying *intensity* instead of power)